# How to convert array to array object,like['in','gs'] to [{"state":"in"},{"state":"gs"}] in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

How to convert array to array object,like

['in','gs'] to [{"state":"in"},{"state":"gs"}]

Comment: You could use `Array.map` like so `array.map(v => ({ state: v}))`

Comment: This question doesn't include an attempt to solve the problem. Please read https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt and https://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch

Answer (score 4, accepted):

map over it and return a new array

```js
let arr = ['in','gs'] 
let newArr = arr.map(item => ({state: item}));   
console.log(newArr);
```